# !Missing dollar inserted

Tags: bibliographies

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[
pdfauthor={derajan},
pdftitle={How to do this},
pdfstartview=XYZ,
bookmarks=true,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
pdftex,
bookmarks=true,
linktocpage=true, % makes the page number as hyperlink in table of content   
hyperindex=true
]{hyperref}


\linespread {1.3}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\marginparwidth 0pt
\oddsidemargin  0pt
\evensidemargin  0pt
\marginparsep 0pt
\topmargin   0pt
\textwidth   6.5in
\textheight  8.5 in

\begin{document}
\setcounter{NAT@ctr}{0}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

When I run this code above , it gives me the error below:

```
line 263 ! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \newblock Insper Working Papers wpe_
line 265 ! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$
line 265 ! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>}
line 265 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\par ...m \@noitemerr {\@@par }\fi \else {\@@par }\fi
```

Here is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.5.24)  24 SEP 2017 14:04
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**coskun.tex
(./coskun.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\ex@=\dimen105
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen106
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count89
\leftroot@=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count91
\DOTSCASE@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen107
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count93
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count94
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count95
\dspbrk@lvl=\count96
\tag@help=\toks16
\row@=\count97
\column@=\count98
\maxfields@=\count99
\andhelp@=\toks17
\eqnshift@=\dimen108
\alignsep@=\dimen109
\tagshift@=\dimen110
\tagwidth@=\dimen111
\totwidth@=\dimen112
\lineht@=\dimen113
\@envbody=\toks18
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks19
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip46
\bibsep=\skip47
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count100
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdwtools/footnote.sty
Package: footnote 1997/01/28 1.13 Save footnotes around boxes
\fn@notes=\box28
\fn@width=\dimen114
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
Package: caption 2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 57.
\captionmargin=\dimen115
\captionmargin@=\dimen116
\captionwidth=\dimen117
\caption@tempdima=\dimen118
\caption@indent=\dimen119
\caption@parindent=\dimen120
\caption@hangindent=\dimen121
)
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count101
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip11
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen122
\lightrulewidth=\dimen123
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen124
\belowrulesep=\dimen125
\belowbottomsep=\dimen126
\aboverulesep=\dimen127
\abovetopsep=\dimen128
\cmidrulesep=\dimen129
\cmidrulekern=\dimen130
\defaultaddspace=\dimen131
\@cmidla=\count102
\@cmidlb=\count103
\@aboverulesep=\dimen132
\@belowrulesep=\dimen133
\@thisruleclass=\count104
\@lastruleclass=\count105
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen134
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty
Package: lscape 2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen135
\Hy@linkcounter=\count106
\Hy@pagecounter=\count107

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count108

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4319.
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 4319.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4319.
Package hyperref Info: Option `linktocpage' set `true' on input line 4319.
Package hyperref Info: Option `hyperindex' set `true' on input line 4319.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4443.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4448.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4451.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4458.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4463.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4688.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count109
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5041.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen136
\Fld@menulength=\count110
\Field@Width=\dimen137
\Fld@charsize=\dimen138
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6295.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6300.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6303.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6310.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 6313.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6320.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6325.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6365.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6369.
\Hy@abspage=\count111
\c@Item=\count112
\c@Hfootnote=\count113
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count114
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count115

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip48
)
(./coskun.aux)
\openout1 = `coskun.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 40.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count116
\scratchdimen=\dimen139
\scratchbox=\box29
\nofMPsegments=\count117
\nofMParguments=\count118
\everyMPshowfont=\toks20
\MPscratchCnt=\count119
\MPscratchDim=\dimen140
\MPnumerator=\count120
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count121
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks21
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
)
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: hyperref package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box30

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 142.
)
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 40.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count122
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 40.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 40.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 40.

(./coskun.out) (./coskun.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `coskun.out'.

 (./coskun.bbl [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.263 \newblock Insper Working Papers wpe_
                                          160, Insper Working Paper, Insper ...
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.265 

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.265 

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\par ...m \@noitemerr {\@@par }\fi \else {\@@par }
                                                  \fi 
l.265 

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

[3])
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 45.
 [4]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 45.
 (./coskun.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 45.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 45.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `coskun.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 45.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7499 strings out of 493089
 111818 string characters out of 6134842
 200683 words of memory out of 5000000
 10867 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 10054 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 36i,5n,38p,242b,500s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></u
sr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/
local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfbx1440.pfb></usr/lo
cal/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1095.pfb></usr/loca
l/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfti1095.pfb>
Output written on coskun.pdf (4 pages, 107475 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 112 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 99 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 55 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post editable code, not a screenshot of code. Incidentally, why did you set the 'biblatex' tag? By the way, the double-backslash after `\end{equation}` looks rather odd. And there should definitely be no reason whatsoever for using Plain-TeX `... \over ...` infix syntax instead of `\frac{...}{...}` in a LaTeX document. None whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the things you suggested but it gave me the same error. I set biblatex deliberately. The problem might come from there. However, I just checked it. Even if I deleted the codes (almost 10 lines from tex and 2 references from bibtex), it gave me the same error.

Comment: sorry, I am trying to figure out how to put it here properly. it will be here soon.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: your example still does not let anyone debug your problem as no one can run it in that form, please make an example that produces the error. meanwhile unrelated to that error, you need to remove the `\\ `  after `\end{equation}`

Comment: from your question and provided code fragment is impossible to say, what is your problem. as you say in comment, this codes are not cause of ti ... can you provide complete small document, beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{diocument}` which demonstrate your error. also provide part log file which show your error, that we can see, what error you receive.

Comment: Hint: in your log file you can possibly find the row of the code that causes the error. Try to include the commands on this row in your MWE or search there for symbols that allowed only in math mode like "_" or ">" etc

Comment: The code you've posted definitely doesn't give rise to the error message(s) you reported initially (but which are now no longer shown). Moreover, since your code no longer features any `\cite` instructions, it's impossible to tell if (and how) any `\cite` instructions may be creating havoc.

Comment: the code as posted produces no error. If you run bibtex on it, it then produces the error that there are no citations so no bibliography is produced.  Delete the generated .bbl file then edit the example so that it produces the error, otherwise no one can help much, well actually the log file shows the issue. I'll answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code posted does not show the problem however your log shows

```
 \newblock Insper Working Papers wpe_
                                          160, Insper Working Paper, Insper ...
```

so one of your bibliography entries in the `.bib` file has the text  `wpe_160`  but `_` is math mode only so the entry should say `wpe\_160` assuming you want a literal `_`